# Round off to the smallest integer value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using this query to round off the numbers and this round off the next value. Now I need to round off to the before value means if the value is 45.67 then the value should be 45. I tried these two queries and still I need to tweak the values.

**Method1:**

```
parsename('$' + convert(varchar,convert(money,round(sum(Column1 * Column2),0)),1),2)
```

**Method2:**

```
parsename('$' + convert(varchar,convert(money,floor(Column1 * Column2),0),1),2)
```

Really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Why are you rounding 45.67 to 45?

Comment: The nearest value to 45.67 is normally regarded to be 46, not 45; so are you tried to round off, or truncate to the largest integer that is smaller than the value?

Comment: use `floor` or `ceiling`functions instead. See my answer.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Why all these conversions? How is floor(Column1 * Column2) different from what you actually want?

Comment: @RowlandShaw - Sorry not the nearest, need to adjust to the previous round off value and means the smallest integer.

Comment: Show your expected value. Why are you using parsename?

Comment: @Horaciux - I would need to show them in integer format.

Answer (score 2):

The CEILING function returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to the specified numeric expression. The FLOOR function returns the largest integer less than or equal to the specified numeric expression. For example, in considering a numeric expression of 12.9273, CEILING returns 13 and FLOOR returns 12. The return value of both FLOOR and CEILING has the same data type as the input numeric expression.

```
SELECT CEILING(12.9273);
Here is the result set.
13

SELECT FLOOR(12.9273);
Here is the result set.
12
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190927%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Never heard of CEILING or FLOOR... very interesting. Thank you

Comment: I have tried floor and still I need to tweak the values.

Comment: @Michael if you need to show trailing zeros `$45.00` remove `parsename`function

Comment: @Michael For int use this: `declare @value int; select @value = Column1 * Column2`

Answer (score 0):

To round down you can use FLOOR()

E.G.

```
DECLARE @number numeric(5,2)
SET @number = 45.67
SELECT FLOOR(@number)
```

You'd get the result `45`

With your example, it looks like it's already working?

```
declare @number1 numeric(5,2)
declare @number2 numeric(5,2)
set @number1 = 1.23
set @number2 = 21.69

select parsename('$' + convert(varchar,convert(money,floor(@number1 * @number2),0),1),2)
select @number1 * @number2
```

Results

```
$26
26.6787
```